# firebase/functions-samples.. /email-users, error: invalid login

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I followed the steps at the [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/email-users) repository but I do not get emails when creating a new account or deleting it etc.

I get the following error:

> Invalid login

I checked if the password was correct with:

```
firebase functions:config:get
```

And it was, so I'm lost now.

Comment: As you've written it now, this question/problem would be a better fit as an issue on the Github repo. If you'd like us to help here, please share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it's quite useful).

Answer (score 1):

See the following instructions for setting up Gmail SMTP for Nodemailer
https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/